What are inactive/active schemas in AWS EventBridge schema registry?
I am working with AWS schema registry and I came across this line where it says:

Inactive schemas will be deleted after two years.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/schema-reference/v1-registries-name-registryname-schemas-name-schemaname.html#v1-registries-name-registryname-schemas-name-schemaname-prop-describeschemaoutput-lastmodified
What does it mean to have an active and inactive schema? I could not find anything related to this in the AWS docs.
If it does delete the schemas in a custom registry, what is the best way of storing and retrieving schemas when AWS deletes them after two years?.
Create schema
